# Plot strategy order on chart

Tags: pine-script

I would like to plot something (an arrow, a label) that could mark on the chart everytime my strategy sets a buy or sell order (which happens under certain conditions but can disappear)

Is there a way in pine script I could do that ?

Here's the extract of the strategy that creates the order :

> strategy.entry("BuyOrder", strategy.long, stop=high+syminfo.mintick, comment="Buy", when = window())

Comment: Whenever your `strategy.entry()` is executed, it plots an arrow. You want something extra?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how I could do that in terms of code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ta.change()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dchange) with [`strategy.position_size`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dposition_size) and [`strategy.opentrades`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dopentrades):

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)


changeCond = ta.change(strategy.position_size, 1) or ta.change(strategy.opentrades,1)
bgcolor(changeCond? color.new(color.red, 80) : na)
```

Comment: The issue with that is it plots only when the order is executed, but I would like to know when an order is created even if it is not executed (ex : if i set a buy order at 4400 but the price never reaches 4400, it will not be executed but I still want something to be plotted)

Comment: Display `longCondition` and `shortCondition` then